# how to build a chrome extension to display the list of current google search

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to build a chrome extension on click on it should display the list(websites/links) of google search results. Suppose I search on google by typing Delhi to Bangalore. Then list of travelling websites/link appears. That list should be display on the console.
 This is the 1st time working on chrome extension. I also took the help of [https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted][1] . But result was not achieved.

I tried find some Api of chrome extension on https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devguide. But not abled to find the appropriate api. I have tried Web Request api.

```
1. manifest.json



 {
            "name": "Search List",
            "description": "Google Search List",
            "version": "0.1",
            "permissions": [
                "declarativeContent",
                "storage",
               "activeTab"
            ],
            "background": {
                "scripts": [
                    "searchListContent.js"

                ],
                "persistent": false
            },
            "page_action": {
                "default_popup": "searchListTemplate.html",
                "default_icon": {
                    "16": "images/get_started16.png",
                    "32": "images/get_started32.png",
                    "48": "images/get_started48.png",
                    "128": "images/get_started128.png"
                },
                "default_title": "Google Search List"
            },
            "icons": {
                "16": "images/get_started16.png",
                "32": "images/get_started32.png",
                "48": "images/get_started48.png",
                "128": "images/get_started128.png"
            },
            "manifest_version": 2
        }

2. searchListContent.js

 chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function () {


    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function () {
         chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
             conditions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
                 pageUrl: { hostEquals: 'www.google.com' },
             })
            ],
            actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
         }]);
     });

     var searchList = document.getElementById("printListId");
     console.log(searchList); });
```

Comment: What is your actual question/what is not working? For what kind of API are you looking?

Comment: The webRequest API won't work here because you need to read the response and it doesn't allow that. You need a content script where you'll be able to set up a MutationObserver and when the page is changed it'll trigger so you can process the links in the page and produce the list out of them.